# RPI 3, how to connect built-in wifi to network A, additional usb wifi adaptor connect to network B

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

RPI 3, running the latest lite version. How can I configure built-in wifi(wlan0) to connect to only the wifi network A, additional usb wifi adaptor(wlan1) connect to network B only?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)
describes how to use different wpa_supplicant.conf files in the "Advanced dhcpcd Configuration" section.

The use of Predictable Network Interface Names is recommended if multiple adapters are in use.

Comment: Thank you! I used different wpa_supplicant files, worked like a charm.